# call other method before action call using asp.net mvc 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I want to call other method or other technique before action call in asp.net mvc 2.

Because I want to set property in variable then to call action in controller.

can any one guide me if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this help http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionfilterattribute.onactionexecuting.aspx ?

Answer (score 1):

You could implement your own controller factory, see [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/shijuvarghese/archive/2008/10/10/asp-net-mvc-tip-dependency-injection-with-structuremap.aspx), and do whatever you like with the controller before you return it.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need to do set is set a controller member variable then a quick and clean method is to override the controller's [initialize method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.initialize.aspx) like so:

```
protected override void Initialize( RequestContext rc) {
    base.Initialize(rc);
    //Add any variable initialization here
    employeeId = rc.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["userid"]["emp_id"];
}
```